# Local database integer data getting string when i push it to algolia

Tags: algolia

Records i'm pushing to algolia are showing as string however it's an integer in my local database.

Answer (score 1):

Well you didn't put any code so I assume your error is here : Algolia is schemaless. You have to do it like said  [in this page :](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/index-configuration/how-should-i-format-my-data)

```
{
  "objectID": 42,             // record identifier
  "title": "Breaking Bad",    // string attribute
  "episodes": [               // array of strings attribute
    "Crazy Handful of Nothin'",
    "Gray Matter"
  ],
  "like_count": 978,          // integer attribute
  "avg_rating": 1.23456,      // float attribute
  "featured": true,           // boolean attribute
  "actors": [                 // nested objects attribute
    {
      "name": "Walter White",
      "portrayed_by": "Bryan Cranston"
    },
    {
      "name": "Skyler White",
      "portrayed_by": "Anna Gunn"
    }
  ]
}
```